# Grabbing Locator Index Automatically

Tags: node.js, selenium, css-selectors, protractor, selenium-chromedriver

I'm going to try to explain this the best I can without making it too complicated. Currently I have a program which automatically grabs an element's locator (id, css, xpath) when I click on an element on a page.

The problem is, the element's css (ID, class name, etc) that I am grabbing is not unique (I cannot change the website)

I know in chrome, when I type $$('#test'), it will bring me a list of locators with ID 'test'. From there I know I could manually find the index of the element. However I want to do this automatically.

My application is essentially a recorder which captures the element locators. I am capturing the element event through selenium webdriver, but I am unable to get the index of that. I know this is a little confusing, but any help would be greatly appreciated.

**By the way, I cannot use xpath.**

Thanks.

Comment: It will be easier to understand if you post your code and the html.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot post html code as it is company property, but I will try my best to get you an example.

Comment: I have some buttons with id test. There are 5 of those on the page that I am recording. All of them have the same exact ID. So when I search on chrome console with $$('#test'), it gives me an array of 5 elements, each one of them pointing to the specific button the page. Now I can manually go and find the index by hovering my mouse over the list of elements given through the console and see which one gets highlighted. But I need to do this automatically through some script.