# How does Chrome generate the CSS selector and XPath?

Tags: css, google-chrome, xpath

When you open a webpage in Chrome and inspect an element, when you select the element and right click again you can choose to copy the CSS selector and XPath selector. I have a project that basically needs to automatically generate the CSS selector and XPath selector based on the given HTML page, so I am wondering what kind of rules Chrome is following on generate the CSS selector and XPath.

I know Chrome generates several kinds of CSS selector. Sometimes it will use `nth-child` after the tag name to specify, and other times it will use class name after tag name, so which one should I choose automatically?

e.g:

```css
html > body > div:nth-child(2) > div > div:nth-child(2) > p > a
```

vs

```css
body > div.custom > div > div.master-body.col-md-10.col-sm-11.col-xs-12 > p > a.button
```

What’s the difference between these two and `nth-child`, which seems easy to break if there are other elements with a different tag inside?

Comment: Choose neither. There are near-infinite different ways to select an element in a complex DOM document: Chrome's suggestion is only one and is created to make sure that every element has its unique selector. This is rarely desired behaviour in reality.

Comment: Right, there are many ways to generate the css selector, I mean I can provide users several ways to choose, but I want to make a default one  as precise as possible. Do you have any suggestions?by the way, can you answer my second question? why the nth-child seems easy to break if there are other element with different tag inside. e.g: p:nth-child(2) will get the second element
<p>one</p>
<p>two</p>
but not working for
<p>one</p>
<div>middle</div>
<p>two</p>

Comment: This problem has been solved many times before, in various different ways. [Here's one that's supposed to be good](https://github.com/autarc/optimal-select). Personally I've never had a need for such functionality!

Comment: `p:nth-child(2)` looks for elements that are both `p` and `:nth-child(2)`. There isn't one in your second example: the second `p` is the third child. `:nth-of-type` does what you mean here.

Comment: Thanks, that's really helpful, one more question is when I get the css selector or xpath, sometimes it is an array, is there any way to specify the index of the array automatically

Comment: Like this example: http://imgur.com/a/dSzOl

Comment: Found a similar question here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41946684/grabbing-locator-index-automatically

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22427476/how-does-chrome-dev-tools-generate-css-selectors (which covers CSS selectors since it pertains to CSS, but the same rules apply to XPath)